# How to set Httponly Cookie to WKHTTPCookieStore

Tags: cookies, wkwebview, httponly

I have a NSHTTPCookie which HTTPOnly flag is `true`.

When I use WKHTTPCookieStore's `setCookie:CompletionHandler` to set cookie, the HTTPOnly flag will automatically convert to `false`.

Than I can read the cookie wanted httpOnly by Javascript code, like "document.cookie"

Comment: I came across the same issue. Do you find any solutions?